# finding maximum values using Oracle / SQL group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a query for a table with 5 columns which are `ID1`, `ID2`, `ID3`, `A`, and `B`. Here, 
`ID1`, `ID2`, and `ID3` form the primary key.

For each `ID1`, find maximum `A`. If two or more `A`s have the maximum values, choose the only one record that has maximum `B`. Finally show the results with corresponding `ID2` and `ID3` values.

For example, for the following table

```
ID1 ID2 ID3   A  B
  1   2   3  10  5 
  1   3   4  30  4
  1   3   5  30  3
  2   2   3   5  1
  2   3   4   9  2
  2   3   5  11  3
```

the query should show the results as follows.

```
ID1 ID2 ID3  Max_A  
  1   3   4     30  
  2   3   5     11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gist of this is to

- add a `ROW_NUMBER` to each row
- restart the number for each `ID1`
- `ORDER`  from high to low on `A` and `B`.
- put it in a `CTE` for easy access on `rn`

**SQL Statement**

```
;WITH q AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID1 ORDER BY A DESC, B DESC) AS rn
  FROM YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM   q
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: +1 but i think you need to switch the * in the CTE for ID1,ID2,ID3, to make it syntatically correct